# Can't sum the elements in an array with Jquery

Tags: jquery

i tried to sum the elements and put the result in a texbox but it only takes the last element of array. What am i doing wrong? (total1 is the id of the texbox.)

```
var diziquantity = [100,200];
var totalqty = 0;
$.each(diziquantity,function(index,element){
  totalqty = parseFloat(element) + totalqty;

});
$("#total1").val(totalqty);
```

Puts 200 in to the textbox, i want it to put 300 instead of 200.

Comment: It's working fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/914hm5y7/

Comment: I have a feeling you've just got `totalqty = parseFloat(element);` in your local code as what you've posted works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have added some changes

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){


 var diziquantity = [100,200];
 var totalqty = 0;
 jQuery.each(diziquantity,function(index,element){
   totalqty = ( parseFloat(element) + parseFloat(totalqty) );
 });

 console.log(totalqty);
 //jQuery("#total1").val(totalqty);

 jQuery("#total1").val(totalqty);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="total1" id="total1" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative, Javascript has `Array.prototype.reduce` for this:

```js
const arr = [100, 200];
let total = arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
console.log(total);
```